# On the connection between vectors, functions and matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functions, vector-spaces

A vector definitely is an element of a vector space. It has often been said that all vectors are matrices (in my opinion, even this assertion needs to have a proof if we really consider vectors in the general sense). On the other hand, matrices (the dimension certainly fixed) are the elements of a vector space, so they are vectors. Therefore the question "does an equivalence between the notions of vectors and matrices exist?" doesn't seem absurd.

---

The general idea of vectors, like elements of the vector spaces, seems to come from the notion of the geometrical vectors that are a subspecies of following bijective functions inside of the n-tuples of a field **F** (the bijection is easy to prove):

\begin{align*}
  f\colon \mathbf F^{n} & \longrightarrow\mathbf F^{n} \\[-1ex]
  (e_{1}, e_{2},.. e_{n}) & \longmapsto (e_{1}+a, e_{2}+b,.. e_{n}+z) \\
a, b,.. z ∈ \textbf{F}
\end{align*}
It is not difficult to prove that these functions compose a vector space.
In case of the geometrical vectors **F** = **R** (and, perhaps, n = 2 or 3 ). Thus, for instance, the vector addition is a simple composition these functons. Hence it seems natural to ask: can the other vectors be thought like a functions? And, if they can, what are those functions? At least, a one way seems to be there: if the vectors, like it has been said in the precedent part, are matrices, they are also a functions, because
matrices are functions. However, this way is very formal and even vain: according with this way the same geometrical vectors are only a functions g:
\begin{align*}
 g\colon 1×\mathbf {K} ⊂ \mathbf {N}×\mathbf{N} & \longrightarrow\mathbf F \\
\end{align*}
that don't look like something related to the vector space and its structure.

Answer (score 1):

It's to be noted that *elements* of a vectors space are called *vectors* NOT because they are *true* vectors but rather because we just wanted to *label* them as such. That is, vectors as *elements* of a vector space is just a label and should not be necessarily taken too literally. This is common practice in mathematics. e.g., in a field $\Bbb F$, the additive identity is *labeled* $0$ even though it may *not* literally be equal to the *number* zero (0), Same for additive inverses, multiplicative inverses, and so on. The motivation behind such a labeling is that they behave like the real number $0\in\Bbb R$ when working in an arbitrary field. This was basically the motivation behind "labeling" elements of a vector space as "vectors".

In fact, functions between vectors spaces (called *linear transformations*) may be represented as matrices but that does NOT imply, in any way, that they must be equivalent entities in a "logical" sense. The major significance of such representations lie in the fact that one representation may be more enlightening in a certain proof/result than another. So, seeking an equivalence is unnecessary when you start realizing they are independent entities given different "*labels*" under different usage.